# Ubuntu doesn’t load after restoring BIOS

Tags: 18.04, bios, acpi

I tried to test something I inadvertently restored the BIOS setting. Now when I press on the power button to turn on the system Ubuntu doesn't load. The only thing that displays is this message.

[image]

I have a lot of data and projects on it.

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu did you change UEFI settings? I have 5 or 7 settings, some optional that I have to redo with every UEFI update as it resets to defaults. You need to review settings. Check that drives are AHCI, Secure boot is off and often others, depending on vendor/model of system. It also looks like you have nVidia but have not installed nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 0):

Access the BIOS setup utility when the computer is booting and change the boot mode from Legacy to UEFI. On the boot device menu, select the option that identifies both the firmware mode and the device. For example, select UEFI: SSD if the bootloader is installed on an SSD.

[image]

- Select the Boot tab.
- Use the up and down arrows to select the appropriate Legacy or UEFI boot mode, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Press F10 to save the changes and exit the screen.

Comment: Legacy mode or UEFI? I couldn’t find the option that you’ve mentioned. Can you tell me more, please?

Comment: @TheMir Anything looking like "Secure boot" could be UEFI.